# weddriver with multiple IE versions

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver

I have two questions!
1. is it possible (and if yes how?) to have multiple IE versions on the same machine?
2. If previous answer is yes, is it possible to start these different versions using webdriver?

I can solve this by using remote webdriver  but i'd like to have all the stuff on one machine

Answer (score 3):

Even with Grid, you can have only one instance of IE running on one machine. But you can always create threads and invoke multiple IEDriver instances. Using threads is not simple and in most cases leads to failures.

Comment: +1. This is absolutely correct. I will point out also that, products purporting to allow it notwithstanding, there is no supported way to run multiple versions of Internet Explorer in a single operating system installation. This is Microsoft's position on the matter, and the IE driver development team has chosen to stay within the limits of support for IE.

Comment: Selenium grid server supports all the multiple versions by using a capabilities object.  Also, the above answer doesn't address the question of testing "multiple versions" and instead addresses a question that wasn't asked "how to run multiple IE at once".

Answer (score 1):

I use a tool called IETester (by Core Services) to run multiple browsers on the same computer.  Unfortunately, it wont work with Selenium.

What you have to do is run multiple Grid Nodes on the same machine, each one with a separately defined "capabilities".   This means you wouldn't set your capabilities in your code/test but instead allow the grid Node to define it.   You can also pass these options on command line to the grid .jar  but I prefer to define the config in a JSON file instead.

```
-browser browserName=internet explorer,version=7,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1
```

NOTE: if the app your testing is HTML4 doctype (defined at the top of the HTML file), then IE goes into "quirks" mode anyway and testing the other IE versions is a mute point, IMHO.  Testing multiple versions of IE makes the most sense with HTML5 apps.